# Using PHP and openssl and storing it in MySQL - can't decrypt data

Tags: php, mysql, openssl

I want to use `openssl_public_encrypt` to encrypt data and store it in a MySQL database. Then, when I need the data, I want to `SELECT` it from the MySQL database and use `openssl_private_decrypt` to decrypt it. After it is encrypted I am using `base64` to encode the data for MySQL and again to decode the data before decrypting it.

Here is the code I am using to encrypt the data and `INSERT` it in the database:

```
<?php
    require_once('default.inc.php');
    mysql_connect_selectdb($host,$username,$password,$database);
    function encrypt($string) {
    $publickey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    PUBLIC KEY HERE
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
        openssl_public_encrypt($string,$encryptedstring,$publickey);
        return $encryptedstring;
    }
$number = base64_encode(encrypt('1234567890123456'));
$qry = "UPDATE table SET number='$number' WHERE id='120006'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
if (!$result) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

The `default.inc.php` file sets error reporting to E_ALL and also defines the mysql connect variables and the `mysql_connect_selectdb()` function. It inserts into the database fine and there is no output to the screen.

Here is the code I am using to `SELECT` it from the database and decrypt it:

```
<?php
require_once('default.inc.php');
mysql_connect_selectdb($host,$username,$password,$database);
$key = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
PRIVATE KEY HERE
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';
function decrypt($string,$privatekey) {
    openssl_private_decrypt($string,$decryptedstring,$privatekey);
    return $decryptedstring;
}
$qry = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='120006'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
if ($result) {
    if (mysql_numrows($result) == '1') {
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $number = decrypt(base64_decode($data['number']),$key);
        echo 'Number: '.$number;
    }
    else {
    echo 'no rows';
}
}
else {
    die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

There is no output to the screen other than `Number:`. I can't figure out why it doesn't decrypt. I can echo the `$data['number']` straight from the database and it shows up fine as base 64 encoded data and also I can echo the data after it has been base 64 decoded and it shows up fine as binary on my screen, however when I try to decrypt it there is no output.

The MySQL field number is `VARCHAR(128)` (have tried `VARBINARY`, `BINARY` and `BLOB`), `VARCHAR` should be fine for `base64`, and it is a `latin1_swedish_ci` collation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: @Matt Why are they being depreciated?

Comment: @EthanH I think that it's about performance and the security features.

Comment: What @Manhim said. Click the link. It's a (non-revenue generating) blog that I and another SOer are putting together, offering updates on widely-used, now-deprecated PHP functions.

Comment: I'll switch then, thanks for the article @Matt

Comment: Are you also using the openssl functions to create the public/private keys, or are you just entering them as text strings in the variables as noted? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: For the public key, do you have these spaces/tabs before it in your code? If yes, try removing them.

Comment: @MikeBrant no I'm not getting any errors and I am using the openssl functions to generate them

Comment: @Manhim no I don't have spaces/tabs, there are some here because otherwise it will not display correctly in the code box will display as plain text

Comment: @EthanH If you assign the result of the openssl_private_decrypt to a variable and dump it, are you actually getting `true` to indicate that the decryption operation was a success?

Comment: Could you give me a code example @MikeBrant? I am confused by what you mean.

Comment: @EthanH Sure: `$result = openssl_private_decrypt($string,$decryptedstring,$privatekey); var_dump($result);`

Comment: @MikeBrant It dumps `NULL` however the `$data['number']` dumps `string(128)` followed by what it contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The column `number` was a `VARCHAR(128)` however the length of the string being inserted was `172`, so therefore the end of the string was cut off. Without the end of the string, it didn't decrypt properly and returned `NULL`.